# Angular : get specific object key data json

Tags: json, angular, object

l have following data json keys objects

```
{
  "23ac54a": [
    25.226,
    54.9333
  ],
  "23ad09a": [
    24.9228,
    55.1319
  ],
  "23ad1b6": [
    24.8367,
    55.148
  ]
}
```

l am trying to pass parameter from page 1 to page 2 . So if that parameter is same value in that data json above i want to get only data under that object key depending on same parameter coming from page 1 .

example if parameter from page 1 is `23ad09a` and he is same in that data json i will take only data under this `23ad09a` from data json above .

So my question is its possible to do that using if statement ? and if its how can i write functionality depending on my code below please ?

My code

```
this.Data = JSON.parse(data.data);
console.log(this.Data)
this.points = Object.keys(this.Data)
  .map(key => this.Data[key])
  .map((position) => ({
    lat: position[1],
    lng: position[2],
  })).filter(position => position.lat && position.lng).forEach(i => {

      console.log(i.lat, i.lng)

      // our work is here


    })
```

Comment: question is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, you want to filter the data e.g. by key === "23ad09a" ?

I made a simple stackblitz to show you how to do this.

As I can see you use position[1] and position[2],  but you should start at [0].

I added

```
.filter(key => key === '23ac54a')
```

where '23ac54a' can be replaced by a variable.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-aoh2h3

(don't forget to expand console to see the printed results in stackblitz)

Comment: your right that what l want . but on your way , i will getting only data under that object key `23ac54a`  example right ?